# How can I use a regex to validate slideshare slideshow URLs?

Tags: regex

I am using [www.slideshare.net](http://www.slideshare.net) to allow my users to display embedded slideshows on their profiles.

I'm using slideshare's api to get the slideshow's id, given the slideshow link that users has to get by clicking 'share' on the slideshow and copy/paste the url:

[image]

What I would need is to validate thoroughly the latter url.

Just to further explain my process, when I have the slideshow's id, I compute the embedded code like so :

`"<iframe src='https://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/" + json.slideshow_id + "' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozillaallowfullscreen></iframe>"`

where json is the object returned by slideshare's api.

A basic regex to answer my question would be:
`^http\://www\.slideshare\.net/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+$`

But it feels a little weak to me :

- I don't want my users to just copy/paste the url in the navigator address bar
- I'm not sure this regex works for all slideshare's slideshows as I'm not a slideshare specialist (does that even exist?)
- Ideally I would like to exclude all other regular urls from [www.slideshare.net](http://www.slideshare.net) that doesn't point to a slideshow.

EDIT 7/12/2014: rewrite

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?
```

More example from [this website](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=url&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ali. But I need to validate embedded presentations slideshare urls, not generic urls.